# How to push a graphql mutation into a component's props properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, mutation

I'm trying to push a graphql mutation into a component's props.

```
export default graphql(logOnMutation)(Login);
```

That line of code above doesn't work. No errors showing, but doesn't provide mutate function into props of component.

But if I write like that:

```
const logOnWithMutation = graphql(logOnMutation)(Login);
export default logOnWithMutation;
```

and write like this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Fragment>
        <logOnWithMutation/>
      </Fragment>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

it works perfectly.

So what am I missing? I need my first option to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision:

import your Login component in your's parent component as default like that `import Login from './containers/login/login';` not through the exact name like `import { Login } from './containers/login/login';`